# How to open pdf files in 3rd party app via React Native?

Tags: react-native

I don't want to use RN libraries to create a pdf viewer, I'd like to click on a file icon and be asked in which installed application would I like to open the file.

Is there any library that allows me that?

Comment: Are you looking to open local pdf files or files hosted online somewhere in the internet ?

Comment: I'm getting file source (b64) from the api

Comment: I think react-native-view-pdf allows you to open pdf in Base64 format as well. I have included the link in the answer below.

Comment: But this library wont allow me to pick a 3rd party app to display the pdf file in, unless I am misunderstanding the docs

Answer (score 8):

I have used [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) in my project. After that, it's easy as doing;

Android

```
const android = RNFetchBlob.android;
android.actionViewIntent(path, 'application/pdf');
```

iOS

```
RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(path);
```

Comment: can you share full code that list all pdf viewer application?

Comment: But, its not working for Android 10. Unable to open the file in Android 10 using `android.actionViewIntent(path, 'application/pdf');`. :(

Comment: @NarendraSingh Check this solution for android https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/pull/317#issuecomment-492635523

However it opens but also close automatically in seconds don't know why.

Comment: @NarendraSingh You can fix this by adding a few things to AndroidManifest.xml. Check the link. https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/749

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you can use `Linking` from react native itself in order to open pdf files such as:

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
});
```

If url is local, you might wanna use something similar to:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
```

`file://${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/file.pdf`.

Or if online, url can be:

```
http://www.example.com/file.pdf
```

You can also try using this package available:

[react-native-view-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-pdf)

Let me know here, how it goes. If this solves your problem, give a upvote. :D)

Comment: I am using RNFS and doing the Linking in the format you are showing, but it's showing me an error like ```Error: Unable to open URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F842ED12-DDAD-4890-B6CA-66F7EBE460A2/Documents/picture1.jpg```

Comment: I got Could not open URL `'file:///storage/emulated/0/prophet_app/File0.pdf'`

Comment: Thanks!! I just imported Linking and use as `onPress={()=>Linking.openURL("https://xx/xx.pdf")}`

Comment: Thanks man !.. Totally worked like a charm with no extra modules.

Comment: Got this error: Could not open URL 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/q.jpg': file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/q.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Answer (score 4):

I could not make it work with Linking for local pdf files. Then i searched more and found [react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer). With this, you can open a pdf as simply as:

```
 import FileViewer from "react-native-file-viewer";
 ... 


 try {
     await FileViewer.open(url, { showOpenWithDialog: true, showAppsSuggestions: true });
 } catch (e) {
     console.warn(TAG, "An error occurred", JSON.stringify(e));
 }
```

Note: The uri passed to the open function is doesn't need any `file://` prefix. Just the normal path, like `RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/mypdf.pdf"`

Answer (score 2):

The Easy way to load remote PDF,try this

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```